# Is there a better way to generate rest api endpoints from an input file in python?

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a project where I need to parse in a body of data which isn't necessarily going to be a static schema. Thus, I can't really hardcode API endpoints, and would like to generate them based on the data i parse in. I'm not very familiar with python & flask, but i think the usual way people would make a rest endpoint is like the following:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello world!"
```

I'm interested in seeing if there is a way to generically define an API endpoint within a method, so that I could generate a multitude of endpoints based on the data i parse in.

```
def create_endpoint(string):
    @app.route(string: str)
    def new_route():
        return "This is a new route"
```

I'll have another endpoint which will list out all of the urls that will be generated so figuring out which routes to make requests to shouldn't be an issue imo. Is this bad practice in general? is there a better way to do this than I am currently thinking of?

Edit: to clarify,
So, i have a global dictionary, I'll call it "dataDict". When parsing my file, i put key value pairs into this dictionary. I want to create functions so that they return the corresponding values to a key; so, the path "/key1" would return the value at dataDict["key1"]

Comment: How would you control what the routes actually return?

Comment: So, i have a global dictionary, I'll call it "dataDict". When parsing my file, i put key value pairs into this dictionary. I want to create functions so that they return the corresponding values to a key; so, the path "/key1" would return the value at dataDict["key1

Comment: Okay, so why not have one route? `/data/<str:key>`, and `return dataDict[key]` from that?

Comment: good point! not sure why i didn't think of it, just got really confused by how the dataset wasn't really strictly following some schema, but that's what query params & such are for. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a route for each, cricket_007's suggestion to use path/query parameters probably works best here.

Comment: Depending on your data, it might make sense to even externalize the global dictionary to a database